# Get the Exact Size of the Zoomed Image inside the Picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, picturebox

I'm using WinForms. In my Form i have a `picturebox`. It's sizemode is set to `Zoom`. If i load an image into the `picturebox` the image will zoom according to the `picturebox` dimensions.

I wanted to know how I can get the size of the zoomed image inside the `picturebox`.

These are some of the things i tried, but this doesn't give me the result i wanted.

```
    private void Debug_Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var pictureWidth = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width; //This gives the size of the picturebox
        //var picturewidth1 = pictureBox1.Image.Width; This gives the actual size of the image


        //var pictureHight = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height; //This gives the size of the picturebox
        //var pictureHight1 = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height; This gives the actual size of the image

        Debug.WriteLine("Width: " + pictureWidth.ToString() + " Height: " + pictureHight.ToString());
    }
```

Example: 
Actual Size of image[image]

`Picturebox` size mode is set to `Zoom`, so it zoomed the image depending on my `picturebox` size:

[image]

How do i find out the zoomed length and width of this image?

Comment: What do you mean by size of zoomed image inside picturebox? The real size of Image?

Comment: For Example, lets say my `picturebox` length: 1000 and Width is 500, and my image length: 2000 and width: 1000. When the image is loaded into the `picturebox` it will re-size it self accordingly. I want to know how to find the length and width of the image that has been re-sized to fit in the `picturebox`. @dotctor

Comment: Zoom preserves the aspect ratio of the image, so you would have to do some calculations on which *maximum* dimension is used, width or height, and then calculate the other number accordingly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should do the math!

```
Image img = //...;
PictureBox pb = //...;

var wfactor = (double)img.Width / pb.ClientSize.Width;
var hfactor = (double)img.Height / pb.ClientSize.Height;

var resizeFactor = Math.Max(wfactor, hfactor);
var imageSize = new Size((int)(img.Width / resizeFactor), (int)(img.Height / resizeFactor));
```

Comment: `pb.ClientSize.Width;`, in case the control uses borders.  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech Nice, added to answer.

Comment: Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox(); 
did i do these 2 lines correctly?

Comment: `Image img = pictureBox1.Image; PictureBox pb = pictureBox1;` @taji01

Comment: Thank you for all your help! im still new to all of this :)

Comment: You're answer is still helping to this day. I was getting stuck trying to draw on my picturebox and finally realised it was the zoom sizeable setting having the extra on the sides/top. Got it with this. Thanks.